# Ruby .group then .map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a scoresheet feature for teachers that keeps track of student's scores on many different objectives.  The ObjectiveStudent is the join table between Objective and Student.  It also contains a column :points for the student's points in that objective.  My current method of loading the scoresheet is incredibly slow because it loads about 900 ObjectiveStudent objects individually.

I've learned how to grab them all at once, and then group them with the needed ids from their objectives and students.

```
@scores = ObjectiveStudent.all
                .group('user_id', 'objective_id').count
```

Result:

```
{[97, 1]=>1, [97, 2]=>1, [97, 3]=>1, [97, 4]=>1, [97, 5]=>1, [97, 6]=>1, [97, 7]=>1, [97, 8]=>1, [98, 1]=>1, [98, 2]=>1, [98, 3]=>1, [98, 4]=>1, [98, 5]=>1, [98, 6]=>1, [98, 7]=>1, [98, 8]=>1}
```

This is very close to what I need.  Each key is a combination of the student_id and objective_id.  But the value is simply a "1" because that's the count.  What I need is for all the 1's to turn into the value from the "Points" column.

So I try this approach,

```
@scores = ObjectiveStudent.all
                .group('user_id', 'objective_id').map(&:points)
```

And it gives me an array from the points column, but the group method seems to be ignored.  I can figure out how to ask for this data in the view, but I'm sure there's got to be a better way.

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]
```

Thank you in advance for any insight.

Comment: What does `obj_studs_for_seminar` return?

Comment: It returns all of the ObjectiveStudents that belong to the given class period. (I named that model "Seminar" to avoid using the word "Class") .  The important part of my question would be the same if we simply replaced @seminar.obj_studs_for_seminar with ObjectiveSeminar.all.  In fact, I'll rephrase my question to avoid that confusion.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You've shown two methods that don't work (one that's clearly wrong, and another where "the group is ignored", whatever that means?), and a final result of `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 20, ...]` -- Again, whatever that means. (Is that the correct result? Why? What was the original data? I don't even know if `points` is supposed to be a single value, a list of values, or a summation of some values.)

Comment: I would find it much more helpful if you provide a [mcve]. Perhaps just 5 `ObjectiveStudent` records, whatever your best attempt is so far, the result, and the desired result.

Comment: I did provide the result and tried to describe the desired result.  It was enough for Nondv to provide an answer that did exactly what I was trying to communicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I understand correctly:

- ObjectiveStudent is an activerecord model for join table.
- There're unique pairs of student and objective (you can't have "john" and "math" twice in a table). This makes sense since it's a join table.
- You basically need a hash where the key is a pair `[student_id, objective_id]` and value is `points`.

In this case, you don't need `#group` at all. This method is used for SQL `GROUP BY` and since all pairs are unique you have nothing to group (every group will contain only one row, that's why you get `1`'s in your first code).

Just do it this way:

```
ObjectiveStudent.pluck(:student_id, :objective_id, :points)
```

`#pluck` is basically low-level `SELECT` that will return you rows from your query result. You will get an array of triplets that you can process further any way you want. For example:

```
rows.reduce({}) do |result, (student, obj, points)|
   result[student] ||= {}
   result[student][obj] = points
   result
end
```

In this example, you get hash where keys are `student_id` and values are hashes of their points by `objective_id`. If you need pairs in keys, just do it:)

Comment: Yes, Sir.  You seemed to understand my problem just great.  Your solution got me exactly where I was trying to go.  And then you edited into a version that was even more helpful.  Cheers!

Comment: One is glad to be of service, sir :)